# Как через socket получить текст из HTML страницы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

У меня есть такая функция:

```
def send_answer(conn, status="200 OK", typ="text/plain; charset=utf-8", data=""):
    conn.send(b"HTTP/1.1 " + status.encode("utf-8") + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Server: simplehttp\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Connection: close\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Content-Type: " + typ.encode("utf-8") + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"Content-Length: " + bytes(len(data)) + b"\r\n")
    conn.send(b"\r\n")  # после пустой строки в HTTP начинаются данные

    answer = """<!DOCTYPE html>"""
    answer += """<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><h1>"""
    answer += data
    answer += """</h1></body></html>"""

    answer = answer.encode("utf-8")

    conn.send(answer)
```

Где `conn - текущее соединение`

Оно отправляет html-страницу клиенту. 
Можно ли как-то отправить встроенный в эту html-страницу JS(или какой угодно другой исполняемый) код, который бы содержал текствое поле для ввода и кнопку "отправить", то есть получить то, что ввел пользователь в поле для текста?

P.S.
Хочу попробовать сделать это без уже существующих flask|django, то есть вообще понять, как можно такое сделать. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Если просто хочется попробовать принять данные от клиента то достаточно вставить html-форму в страницу и добавить кнопку submit.

Comment: Нельзя ли поподробнее как это можно сделать?